# 2 x 10 random generated numbers have the same sum c#

Tags: c#, listbox

I have 2 listboxes that i need to put 10 random generated numbers in. Then i need to calculate the sum of listbox 1 and the sum of listbox 2 and compare them to see which one is bigger. I do get different numbers in each listbox but for some reason the sum of the listboxes is always the same. How do i make it that the sum is different per listbox.
this i my code at the moment.

```
 private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Random random = new Random();

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        listBox2.Items.Clear();


        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            int nummer = random.Next(20);
            int nummer2 = random.Next(20);
            listBox1.Items.Add(nummer);
            listBox2.Items.Add(nummer2);
        }




        if (addListbox1() > addListbox2())
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Listbox1 heeft de hoogste waarde namelijk " + Convert.ToString(addListbox1());
            listBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            listBox2.BackColor = Color.Red;


        }

        else
        {

            textBox1.Text = "Listbox2 heeft de hoogste waarde namelijk " + Convert.ToString(addListbox2());
            listBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            listBox2.BackColor = Color.Green;


        }



    }
    private int addListbox1()
    {
        int listbox1total = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < listBox1.Items.Count;)
        {
            listbox1total += Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[k++]);
        }
        return listbox1total;
    }

    private int addListbox2()
    {
        int listbox2total = 0;
        int k = 0;

        while(k < listBox2.Items.Count)
        {
            listbox2total += Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[k++]);

        }
        return listbox2total;
    }
```

Comment: You've made a *typo*:  `listbox2total += Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[k++]);` should be `listBox2.Items`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *typo* (an old story of *copy + paste*) in the code:

```
listbox2total += Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[k++]);
```

should be

```
// please, notice "listBox2.Items"
listbox2total += Convert.ToInt32(listBox2.Items[k++]);
```

i.e. `listbox2total` should be the sum of `listBox2.Items`.

In order to *avoid* such errors, change the design, *do not copy yourself*, extract methods:

```
// Easiest, but not thread safe
private static Random random = new Random();

private static void FillBox(ListBox box, int count = 10) {
  box.Items.Clear();

  box.Items.AddRange(Enumerable
    .Range(0, count)
    .Select(x => (Object) random.Next(20))
    .ToArray());
}

private static int SumBox(ListBox box) {
  return box.Items
    .OfType<Object>()
    .Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
}

...

FillBox(listBox1);
FillBox(listBox2);

if (SumBox(listBox1) > SumBox(listBox2)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You should done the manual calculation during your debug quest :)

Comment: @Matosh: *copy + paste* is often treacherous one; do not copy yourself - extract methods - and you'll have the code much easier to read and debug.